# mysql select with inner join giving me looping result

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Hi folks I am stumped with a problem I'm getting with the following mysql query:

```
SELECT 
tp.ID AS tpid, 
p.firstName AS pfname, 
p.lastName AS plname, 
p.dob AS pdob, 
fix.homeTeamID AS fixhtid

FROM fixtures AS fix

INNER JOIN teamSeason AS ts ON fix.homeTeamID = ts.ID
INNER JOIN teamPlayers AS tp ON tp.teamSeasonID = ts.ID
INNER JOIN person AS p ON tp.personID = p.ID

WHERE fix.homeTeamID =2
```

I am expecting 9 rows to result with this query but instead there are over 180 rows where the original 9 rows are being repeated 19 times.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this and was wondering if someone could help me - my brain is mush.

I have tried to remove "fix.homeTeamID AS fixhtid" from the query but it does not stop the looping result.

Is there some way to only show the result without looping?

Should I post the related mysql tables online so you can see?

Thanks

Pete

**UPDATE**

I have updated my sql query to this:

```
SELECT 
tp.ID AS tpid, 

p.firstName AS pfname, 
p.lastName AS plname, 
p.dob AS pdob,

fix.homeTeamID AS fixhtid


FROM fixtures AS fix

INNER JOIN teamSeason AS ts 
ON ts.ID=fix.homeTeamID

INNER JOIN teamPlayers AS tp 
ON tp.teamSeasonID = ts.ID

INNER JOIN person AS p 
ON p.ID = tp.personID

WHERE fix.homeTeamID =2

GROUP BY tpid
```

as suggested by Deepu. I added the "GROUP BY" and it has fixed my result. Thank you so much Deepu and everyone else that took the time to respond.

**Second Update**

I have updated the query again to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tp.ID AS tpid,
    p.firstName AS pfname,
    p.lastName AS plname,
    p.dob AS pdob,

    fix.homeTeamID AS fixhtid

    FROM fixtures AS fix

    INNER JOIN teamSeason AS ts
    ON fix.homeTeamID=ts.ID

    INNER JOIN teamPlayers AS tp
    ON tp.teamSeasonID=ts.ID

    INNER JOIN person AS p
    ON tp.personID=p.ID

    WHERE fix.homeTeamID=2
```

as suggested by Strawberry and John in the name of best practice I have replaced "GROUP BY" in place of "SELECT DISTINCT"

Thanks folks. I have learned something new.

Comment: user `group by` in your query with appropriate field..

Comment: Probably one of the columns in your JOIN condition is wrong,and it gets a cross join.

Comment: Yes, you should post the tables. Even better, add them here and also to [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: Hi Deepu, I will google "GROUP BY" now and post back with my result. thanks for responding

Comment: post the related tables and what u want to retrive

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of GROUP BY is inappropriate, and can in some circumstances lead to misleading results. Use the DISTINCT operator if DISTINCT results are desired. Note that this is not a performance issue.

Comment: have u tried SELECT distinct tp.ID

Comment: OK Strawberry and John, I will try SELECT distinct tp.ID and post back.

Answer (score 2):

You want the JOINS to ADD data based on your original data from fixtures. Then you should use LEFT JOIN

[image]

Comment: ...on the (not unreasonable) assumption that you're only selecting unique entities from each table